# vba code for copying a string if it contains a certain value

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, worksheet-function

Hi I'm looking on how to edit my code so that instead of turning the font colour of the start of the string red and bold, it pastes these strings into another worksheet, however ever time I try to edit it I always end up with a run time error. Any help would be appreciated, here is my current code:

```
Sub colorText()

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim startPos As Integer
    Dim totalLen As Integer
    Dim searchText As String
    Dim endPos As Integer
    Dim testPos As Integer

     ' specify text to search.
     searchText = "(9)"

    ' loop trough all cells in selection/range
     For Each cl In Range("A:A")
      totalLen = Len(searchText)
      startPos = InStr(cl, searchText)
      testPos = 0

      Do While startPos > testPos
         With cl.Characters(startPos, totalLen).Font
          .FontStyle = "Bold"
          .ColorIndex = 3
         End With

    endPos = startPos + totalLen
    testPos = testPos + endPos
     startPos = InStr(testPos, cl, searchText, vbTextCompare)
  Loop

Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Using Filter in VBA you should be able to do it fast and it may not require loop. Does your data begin in Cell A1? Are there no headers in the test column?

Comment: I would advice against using a whole column as range might lead to some problems. Is the position of the searchText important for you or do you just want to copy the string to another sheet if the searchText is found withing the cl.value?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the code you have posted.  What line of your code has the error?  Which line of your code is the modification where you are trying to do the `Copy` operation?

Comment: Yes my data begins in cell A1 and there are no headers, the position of the searchText isn't important, I just want to be able to create a command where it searches through my worksheet and copies the strings with the bit I want as there is a lot of data to search through and will save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to what you said I assume this is what you are looking for?
Your current code doesn't really make sense if the position of the SearchString within the String to search is not relevant as you said.

```html
Sub CopyMatchedValuesToSheet()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRowSource As Long, i As Long
Dim SearchString As String
Dim cell As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

SearchString = "2" ' Set SearchString value or use the one below if you want to change it each time

'SearchString = Application.InputBox("Give a string", "SearchString", Type:=2)

i = 1

With ws1
    LastRowSource = .Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    
    For Each cell In .Range("A1:A" & LastRowSource) ' Change to A2 if it has header
        If InStr(cell.Value, SearchString) > 0 Then
            ws2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = cell.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

You can use the following to clear the Sheet2 each time just change the code to:

```
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") 
ws2.Cells.Clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly anderstood your problem, you have just to construct the string that you want to copy, and assign it to the cell you wante :

```
Dim temp as String
If Not startPos = 0 Then
    temp = Mid(cl, startPos)   
    Sheets("sheet2").Cells(cl.Row, cl.Column) = temp
End If
```